# Retrieve data from Array to text-boxes on select change

Tags: vuejs2

I want to auto-populate data in text-boxes for in VUE. I have this set of array.

```
[
  {"ID":"1","Name":"JOHN DOE","Email":"JohnDoe@GMAIL.COM","Phone Number":"58656","Address":"Somewhere"},
  {"ID":"2","Name":"JANE ZOE","Email":"JohnDoe@GMAIL.COM","Phone Number":"9969","Address":"Anywhere"},
  {"ID":"3","Name":"JENNY JAMES DOE","Email":"JJames@GMAIL.COM","Phone Number":"888888","Address":"Everywhere"}
]
```

`CODE PEN` https://codepen.io/hiro-john/pen/jOOwwza?editors=1010`

If anyone select, 'JOHN DOE' from the Dropdown Name , his details should be auto-populate to the respective fields which are 'Email, Phone & Address' from the Array List. User can add more than 1 Person and each Person data should populate base on 'Name' Dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

Used this function to search inside the Array.

```
function indexWhere(array, conditionFn) {
    const item = array.find(conditionFn)
    return array.indexOf(item)
  }
```

And bind the value on Select Change Event.

```
const index = indexWhere(items, item => item.Name === name)
this.shareholders[id].Address = items[index].Address;
this.shareholders[id].Email = items[index].Email;
this.shareholders[id].Phone = items[index].Phone;
```

Updated `CODE PEN` https://codepen.io/hiro-john/pen/jOOwwza?editors=1010